# Removing character column from another character column on R

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I am simply trying to remove one character col from another character col on R DF, but something is just not right.
Below is the input and desired output

Dataframe: hypo_38

```
Chromosome.   Name. 
chrx          chrX12345AG 
chr9          chr967890TC
```

desired output

```
Chromosome.   Name. 
chrx          12345AG
chr9          67890TC
```

attempts:

```
# 1st try
hypo_38<-hypo_38%>% 
  mutate(Name = str_remove(Name, fixed(Chromosome)))

# 2nd try
hypo_38$clean_string <- mapply(sub, paste0(hypo_38$Chromosome, "$"), ""
                           , hypo_38$Name)
# 3rd try
setDT(hypo_38)[,clean_string:=stringr::str_remove(hypo_38$Name,   paste0(hypo_38$Chromosome, "$"))]

# 4th try 
hypo_38 <- hypo_38 %>%mutate(New = str_remove(hypo_38$Name,
                                            paste0(hypo_38$Chromosome,"$")))
```

For some reason, none of the codes above work. Would anyone please give an insight on this?

Answer (score 0):

You simply have unmatching cases. Just ensure you to `ignore_case` You can therefore use `regex(x, ignore_case = TRUE)` or simply `regex(x, TRUE)` since `ignore_case` is the enxt parameter after `x`

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Name  = str_remove(Name., regex(Chromosome., TRUE)))

  Chromosome.       Name.    Name
1        chrx chrX12345AG 12345AG
2        chr9 chr967890TC 67890TC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(chromosome = c("chrx", "chr9"),
             name = c("chrx12345AG", "chr967890TC"))

output <- df %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(name_trim = gsub(chromosome, "", name))
```

```
output
# A tibble: 2 × 3
# Rowwise: 
  chromosome name        name_trim
  <chr>      <chr>       <chr>    
1 chrx       chrx12345AG 12345AG  
2 chr9       chr967890TC 67890TC
```

EDIT: As in other answer, will have to add the argument ignore.case = TRUE to the gsub call

Answer (score 0):

A **base R** approach using `sub`

```
setNames(data.frame(
  df$Chromosome., 
  sub(paste(unique(df$Chromosome.), collapse="|"), "", df$Name., 
    ignore.case=T)), colnames(df))
  Chromosome.   Name.
1        chrx 12345AG
2        chr9 67890TC
```